# SUMIFS for Array considering Day and Number - Excel Formula

Tags: excel, function, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have a data sheet include the Day (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Etc.), then it provide the another data 0 to 4 , So then Name wise data available in the sheet.

I need to get the summary for another table, I tried with SUMIFS, but It not work to get the data range C2:L50.

I need solution for Excel sheet but I created sample google sheet for easy reference,

Please help on this.

Best regard
Indika

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e6FcwEGbwVVIx2Y3upog7YOjUtHsUOczJs4a-nnEHhU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula in `O2`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$2:$L$112*($A$2:$A$112=O$1)*($B$2:$B$112=$N2))
```

Drag it right and down.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Insert a new column between *B* & *C*, as well as *L* & *M*.

Your spreadsheet should look like this.
[image]

In Cell C2 type: `=CONCAT(A2,B2)`

Extend this all the way down.

In Cell L2 type: `=SUM(D2:M2)`

Extend this all the way down.

Then in Cell Q2 type: `=VLOOKUP(CONCAT(Q$1,$P2),$C$1:$N$112,12,FALSE())`
And extend all across the table.

You should end up with something like this.
[image]

Then if you wish to, you can hide columns *C* & *N*.

Answer (score 0):

Just paste this formula in O2, no need to drag it:

```
=BYCOL(O1:U1,lambda(b,byrow(N2:N6,lambda(a,sum(filter(C2:L,B2:B=a,A2:A=b))))))
```

[image]